# css3.0 - content attribute

Tags: jquery-ui, css

I have written a css file

```
.atleastTwoChars:after {
   content: "2*";
   float: left;
   width: 16px;
   height: 14px;
   border: 0;
   margin: 2px 3px 0px 3px;
   color: red;
}
```

I have used like this

```
<nobr>
<input type="hidden"
       name="ctl00$objContentPageTag$spzContactInformation$txt_sContactZipCode$objHidden"
       id="ctl00_objContentPageTag_spzContactInformation_txt_sContactZipCode_objHidden" value="0">
<input name="ctl00$objContentPageTag$spzContactInformation$txt_sContactZipCode$objTextBox" 
       type="text"
       id="ctl00_objContentPageTag_spzContactInformation_txt_sContactZipCode_objTextBox" 
       class="xqh_LookUpTextBox_Edit">
<span id="ctl00_objContentPageTag_spzContactInformation_txt_sContactZipCode_spanImgMandatory" 
      class="atleastTwoChars">
</span>
</nobr>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#ctl00_objContentPageTag_spzContactInformation_txt_sContactZipCode_spanImgMandatory')
    .removeClass("xqh_LookUpTextBox_ImgMandatory")
    .addClass("atleastTwoChars");
$('img[id*="txt_sContactZipCode_imgMandatory"]').remove();
```

problem: content (2*) should be displayed at the end of the text box but it is displaying at the start like this.

[image]

Comment: Why are you using CSS3 in a document with *obsolete elements*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `float: right;` from your CSS: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Cm5nX/).

Incidentally, according to W3, `nobr`:

> [...is] entirely obsolete, and must not be used by authors...

Reference:

- [Obsolete features, at the W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features)

Answer (score 1):

The `float: left;` will make it display at the start of the line. Perhaps you want to use `display: inline-block;` instead. Or just remove the float, height and width.